# UITableView reloadData with empty array

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am deleting all the items in `UITableView`. And thus the array from which I am loading the `UITableView` has count = 0. After deleting the last item in array, on reloading the table, I am getting error at `numberofRowInSection`.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [arrProjects count];
}  


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"");
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [tableProject beginUpdates];
    Project *project = [arrProjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[CommonModel shared]DeleteProjectDetails:project.ProjectId];
    [arrProjects removeObject:project];
    [self reloadTableProject:YES];
    [tableProject endUpdates];
    }

}  


-(void) reloadTableProject:(BOOL)isReloadRequired
{
    //[arrProjects removeAllObjects];
    arrProjects = [[CommonModel shared]GetAllProjects];

    if(isReloadRequired)
        [tableProject reloadData];
}
```

This is the error :

> 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of
>   rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be
>   equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the
>   update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from
>   that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
>   rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

I am getting this error every time, not only when the array is empty.

Comment: Have you set the numberofRowInSection to be the count of your data source array?

Comment: can you post the code from where you delete all objects in that array

Comment: @LeeJPollard : Yes I have.

Comment: "I am getting error" - cool! ......... What kind may that be?

Comment: It seems that you do not remove the object from arrProjects, but only from the singleton CommonModel object that handles this array of projects, can you show me code for [self reloadTableProjects..]

Answer (score 2):

Set :

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [_datasourceArray count];
}
```

To empty your TableView, do :

```
[_datasourceArray removeAllObjects];
[_tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the object from arrProjects too, inside UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete,

```
[arrProjects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

it is also good to include

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates] and [self.tableView endUpdates]
```

when you start and end the removal of these objects

Comment: Tried this but not working. I am updated the code in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [arrProjects count];
}  


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"");
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        Project *project = [arrProjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[CommonModel shared]DeleteProjectDetails:project.ProjectId];
        [arrProjects removeObject:project.ProjectId];
        [self reloadTableProject: YES];
    }

}
```